# how to get x-gm-labels for email

Tags: c, gmail, gmail-imap

I am trying to understand how can I get gmail labels (`x-gm-labels`) for an email in C.
I checked, that builds of libetpan support `x-gm-labels` extension.

Any idea how to write a sample code to put it all together?

Comment: Are you sure that authors of the lib check stackoverflow? May be it's better to ask them directly? https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/commit/01b2aedbd3ff8febe85beb7227f81895bb2eee3a they committed this 3 months ago.

Comment: I am pretty sure somebody has tried this. Any directions (like IMAP calls itself) will be also useful

Comment: The functionality you're asking for exists in [`src/low-level/imap/xgmlabels.c`](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/src/low-level/imap/xgmlabels.c) and [its header file](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/src/low-level/imap/xgmlabels.h). It's unclear how the author is parsing this, short of the [small set of included test files](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/tree/master/tests). Given the lack of usage documentation and robust examples, this is a good scenario where you should, indeed, ask the author.

Comment: @MrGomez you're right.,however I have reflected in my message everything that can be found related with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. From tracing [this check-in from the original author](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/commit/01b2aedbd3ff8febe85beb7227f81895bb2eee3a), I discovered the code welded into the default handling behavior of [libetpan](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan)'s IMAP support.

Well, it turns out the author [provides an example of how to set up an IMAP connection successfully.](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/tests/imap-sample.c) Instead of spooling out all of the code, here's the bit you should be concerned with:

```
static char * get_msg_att_msg_content(struct mailimap_msg_att * msg_att,
  size_t * p_msg_size)
{
    clistiter * cur;

    /* iterate on each result of one given message */
    for(cur = clist_begin(msg_att->att_list) ; cur != NULL ;
      cur = clist_next(cur)) {
        struct mailimap_msg_att_item * item;

        item = clist_content(cur);
        if (item->att_type != MAILIMAP_MSG_ATT_ITEM_STATIC) {
            continue;
        }

    ...
```

According to my backtrace of the code, your ticket is `struct mailimap_msg_att_item`. The `att_type` you're looking for here is `MAILIMAP_MSG_ATT_ITEM_EXTENSION`, and from there, you should walk the data structures until you find `MAILIMAP_EXTENSION_XGMLABELS`.

Something like this should isolate them:

```
if (item->att_type == MAILIMAP_MSG_ATT_ITEM_EXTENSION) {
    if (item->att_data.att_extension_data->ext_type == 
      MAILIMAP_EXTENSION_XGMLABELS) {
        // ... do something ...
    }
}
```

(**Warning: untested code.**)

From here, you can perform more deeply interrogative inspection of the structs being used. The salient files are all contained in [`src/low-level/imap`](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/tree/master/src/low-level/imap), except for [the test file](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/tests/imap-sample.c). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of IMAP extensions .. see [Gmail IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions) and [Gmail Labels](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions?hl=es#x-gm-labels)

a few examples:

[List all Gmail labels](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/list-all-gmail-labels)

[Label message with Gmail system label](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/label-message-with-gmail-system-label-starred)

Also check the comment of MrGomez that gives a good explination about the functionality that you're asking.

Comment: -1 I don't see how this, at all, can help the OP... (Except that it is fetching mail.)

Comment: @RedX I do not understand why you down vote., when my answer is pretty clear!?!

Comment: He clearly tagged his message as C and your are throwing C# code snippets at him from some random lib...

Comment: and CLEARLY i make a qoute about the comment of @MrGomez!

Comment: in fact the comment of MrGomez, should be as a accepted answer and not as a comment.

Comment: I'm leery about writing a documentation walk as my answer unless I feel it coherently and completely solves the issue. Given the need, however, I'm going to take a look at this again later, just to see if I can get a simple example together. No promises, but the API seems simple enough if it's indeed functional. Thank you for your thoughts.